# IIS6 Classic ASP WMI Permissions

Tags: vbscript, iis-6, wmi

I'm developing a simple internal Classic ASP website (served by IIS6) to help reboot a handful of remote computers.

The App Pool is running under a set of credentials that is an admin on this group of computers, but whenever attempting to connect to any of the remote computers with WMI I recieve an access denied error.

I've tried to connect a number of ways:

```
 WbemScripting.SWbemLocator.ConnectServer(sComputerName, "\root\cimv2\")

 Getobject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Delegate," & _
     "authority=kerberos:OurDomain\" & sComputerName & "}!" & _
     "\\" & sComputerName & "\root\cimv2")
```

I am able to get the code to work if I pass credentials in the ConnectServer() method but we'd rather not store credentials in code...

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you configure delegation inside active directory at the computer objects?
Only then delegation from the web server over a account to another remote computer will work.

See screenshot where to configure.
[image]